# Join two pivot query results into one single table

Tags: sql

I have written two pivot query that produces following T1 and T2 and I am trying to merge the results together as one single table. I am stuck here, because the following query searches with two different value column in the pivot query. How would I join them as one single table?

```
select
                 FileID, 
                 Worksheet,
                 [Index], 
                 ISNULL([Attachment],0) as [Attachment]

        from (select  FileID, 
                  Worksheet,
                  [Index],
                  Label, 
                  Data
        from IT.[dbo].[IT_DATA]
        where FileID = 18265
        and Worksheet = 'Summary' 
        and [Index] <>'0') t       

        PIVOT
        (max([Data]) 
              for [Label] in ([Attachment])
        )piv
```

Query 2:

```
select
                 FileID, 
                 Worksheet,
                 Label, 
                 LOB,
                 ISNULL([1],0) as 1_Share,
                 ISNULL([2],0) as 2_Share,  
                 ISNULL([3],0) as 3_Share,
                 ISNULL([4],0) as 4_Share,
                 ISNULL([5],0) as 5_Share       

        from (select   FileID, 
                  Worksheet,
                  [Index],
                  Label, 
                  LOB, 
                  Data
        from IT.[dbo].[IT_DATA]
        where FileID = 18265       
        and Label = 'Share') s
        PIVOT
        (max([Data]) 
              for [Index] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
        )piv
```

Table 1: 
The following table will always have only these five indexes and I need to merge them with the 15 LOB columns of Table 2. I am trying the merge the results from two tables and make the final table look like in the picture file

```
FileID      Worksheet   Index   Attachment

  18265     Summary       1           0

  18265     Summary       2           0 

  18265     Summary       3          200000000

  18265     Summary       4           0

  18265     Summary       5           0
```

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I am using MS SQL server